# Delete multiple lines if one line contains certain string in notepad++

Tags: command-line, email, notepad++

I have multiple lines for my website and now I want to clear up a few of them.

Is there a way I can mark (or atleast delete) groups of lines that all contain a certain string? For example.

```
====================================
Account: emailaddress1@email.com:password
Orders:
No orders found.
====================================

====================================
Account: emailaddress2@email.com
Orders:
Item 1.
Item 2.
Item 3.
====================================

====================================
Account: emailaddress3@email.com
Orders:
No orders found.
====================================
```

I have that but on a large scale and I want to remove the whole group (including spaces) that contain the string No orders found or preferable mark them so I can move them to a different document.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if Notepad++ supports it but you can use a regex pattern like this one: `'=(.*)=(.*)No\ orders\ found\.(.*)=(.*)='` and replace the match with an empty string `''`. I think that'll match anything that starts with a row of `'='` has `'No orders found.'` in the middle and ends with another row of `'='` (I haven't checked it yet).

Comment: Have you tried "Find and Replace" option?. Press Ctrl+H and provide "Find What" and "Replace With" and then click on Replace All. Will this helps?

Comment: @vembutech unfortunately this will only remove the string I enter and as the email:pass is dynamic and changes it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this work around

press ctrl+H to open replace windows(search mode: Regular expression)

```
find : \r\nNo orders found
Replace with :No orders found
```

This will give the output like below and replace only the group which contains "No orders found"

```
====================================
Account: emailaddress1@email.com:password
Orders:No orders found

====================================
```

Step 2:

```
find : \r\nOrders:No orders found
Replace with :Orders:No orders found
```

This will give the output as follows

```
Account: emailaddress1@email.com:passwordOrders:No orders found
```

Now find the word "No orders found" and delete entire line

```
find : \r\n.*No orders found
Replace with :
```

Hope this helps!